# Drop-able in all possible places

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am currently building a website designer, and one of the core features is to be able to drag & drop to rearrange elements. I have been working on this feature for a few days and have come unstuck a few times. The most important **note** about this drag and drop system is that the drag-able element can be dropped anywhere within the **master** container and it will *Snap  into place* so there will be no absolutely positioned elements otherwise the element won't *Snap into place*.

So first of I started by just building the core draggable bit where you can drag the element, then when you drop the element I am using `document.elementFromPoint()` to get the element where the cursor position is (*note: I have to hide the draggable element otherwise it will return that*).

Now I have the element closest to the cursor the main problem is figuring out where the draggable element needs to go relative to that element, because there are 4 options `append - prepend - insertBefore - insertAfter`. I have managed to get `append - prepend & insertBefore` working but it's not reliable enough because all I am going is using the height and offset of the target to determine either `append or prepend` and I am increasing the `Y` parameter on the `getFromPoint` to see if I hit a different element in a short distance to determine `insertBefore`. Here is the code I have so far.

```
box.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (!dragging) return;
    dragging = false;
    var thisEl = this; // the drag-able element

    // Hide 
    this.style.display = 'none'; // hide the element so we can get 
                                 // document.elementFromPoint

    var el = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY), // target
        elH = el.offsetHeight, // height of target
        elT = el.offsetTop; // offset of target

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) { // This is a weird part see the reference at the bottom
        var newEl = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY + i);
        if (newEl !== el) {
            this.style.display = 'block';
            this.style.position = 'static';
            return newEl.parentNode.insertBefore(thisEl, newEl);
        }
    }

    if (e.pageY < elT + (elH / 2)) { // if the pageY is less than the target offset + half of the height, that's how I am calculating prepend
        el.appendChild(this);
        el.insertBefore(this, el.firstChild);
    } else {
        el.appendChild(this); // else append;
    }

    this.style.display = 'block';
    this.style.position = 'static'; // Snap back in with 'static'
});
```

This is just my `mouseup` event the one that does all of the work. the other events just make the element draggable, not really important.

Here is a fiddle

## **http://jsfiddle.net/mLX5A/2/**

So if that did not *ask* the question then here's a short version.

My drag-able element needs to be able to be dropped anywhere and snap into. What is the best way to do this because the way I have done it in the fiddle is definitely not good. How can I detect where the element needs to go relative to the target on `mouseup`.

Reference to weird section.

Here's how it works (warning, it's not good). When I get the target element with `elementFromPoint` I then create a loop that will loop 15 times and increment the `Y` value that goes into the `elementFromPoint` so basically the `elementFromPoint` is moving down `15px` and if it hits a new element within that short space I am assuming that you want to insert the element before the target.

I am more than happy to receive answers that have nothing to do with this code as that would benefit other users too.

I would like to note that the container that will have drag-able is the main part of the designer. So it is not a choice for me to have all absolutely positioned elements and I wouldn't really be a good idea to put a element in every possible place so that I can detect where the drag-able element has to go because whatever is in that container will be a quality result with no unnecessary content.

I would also like to note that my application **does not** and **will not** ever support and old browsers ie **IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9**

Comment: Just the usual question: are you avoiding a framework like jQuery for any reason? Or does this have to be plain JS?

Comment: @Hless In my project I'm using angular.js and jQlite. jQuery's slogan is ***write less, do more*** well the problem isn't the amount of code it's how to do it. I mean, I'm fine with jQuery answers because once I see what the answer's point is then I will have no problem writing it in vanilla

Comment: I see that you have <br> in your code but no blocks. that would be really painful to handle. I will try to see what I can do but, do you need it with a "snap in" effect or can we work with absolute positioning?

Comment: The idea is that when the element is dropped it will go back to its original styles and all of the dragable styles will be removed, the element is just to be paced in a different position, you can forget about the breaks, I don't think I will be dealing with any of those in the project anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here since your fiddle seems to be working for me. Apart from some user-select/disableSelection feature is needed, the snapping works throughout.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It does work ok, but if the elements are different sizes it's weird because I'm calculating the insertBefore by increasing the pageY by 1px each time to see if i come across another different element, it's just not reliable enough. and am looking for a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you don't want to use jQuery UI. It's a stable, well architected library with lots of support. The size of your application will increase with less than a 100kb. But even if it grew larger, this library will not necessarily put any significant load on your servers as it is accessible from several CDNs. It generally seems to be a bad approach to add the count of the number of lines of the library to your project's total. In the current case I have no clue why jQ seems to be so evil to you compared to several hundred lines of custom (error prone) code.

Comment: @allprog You don't include jQuery & jQuery UI into your Angular.js Application just to use jQuery UI Sortable.

Comment: @Pinocchio if it prevents me from having to write a lot of buggy code, then I'd happily include that rather than spending days with debugging. Especially if this is a really confined part of the application. I'm not a web developer, you are, and you have your preferences. I'm not trying to teach you, I'd rather be willing to learn. What I'm trying to convey is that sometimes it worth thinking over the cost and benefit of an option that has such a huge potential yield in any software. (Unless it's a mission critical system with SIL 5 certification.) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChaseMoskal has a nice solution to the problem using contenteditable="true":

HTML

```
<!--====  DragonDrop Demo HTML
Here we have two contenteditable <div>'s -- they have a dashed bottom-border dividing them, and they contain various text content. The first <div> contains structured block content, and the second <div> contains Unstructured, unwrapped content.
====-->

<div contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Athenagora Lenoni Incommunicabile: Structured Content</h1>
    <h2>Cellam modico illius ergo accipiet si non ait est Apollonius.</h2>

    <a class="fancy">
        <img src="http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/809/picture195z.jpg" />
        <caption>Hola!</caption>
    </a>

    <p>Volvitur ingreditur lavare propter increparet videns mihi cum. Tharsis ratio puella est Apollonius in deinde plectrum anni ipsa codicellos, jesus Circumdat flante vestibus lumine restat paralyticus audi anim igitur patriam Dianae. 'Iuraveras magnifice ex quae ad per te sed dominum sit Mariae Bone de his carpens introivit filiam. Plus damna nautis unum ad te. Puto suam ad quia iuvenis omnia. Etiam quantitas devenit regi adhibitis sedens loculum inveni.</p>
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
    <strong>Unstructured Content:</strong> Toto determinata se est se ad te finis laeta gavisus, laetare quod una non ait mea ego dum est Apollonius. Intrarem puella est in deinde cupis ei Taliarchum in, tharsiam vis interrogat Verena est Apollonius eius ad suis. Antiochus ac esse more filiam sunt forma ait Cumque persequatur sic. Imas rebum accusam in fuerat est se sed esse ait Cumque ego. Secundis sacerdotem habemus ibi alteri ad quia, agere videre Proicite a civitas exulto haec. Supponite facultatibus actum dixit eos. Neminem habere litore in deinde duas formis. Quattuordecim anulum ad nomine Hesterna studiis ascende meae puer ut sua, eiusdem ordo quos annorum afferte Apollonius non ait in.
    <br /><br />
    Deducitur potest contremiscunt eum ego Pentapolim Cyrenaeorum tertia navigavit volente in fuerat eum istam vero cum obiectum invidunt cum. Christe in rei sensibilium iussit sed, scitote si quod ait Cumque persequatur sic. Amet consensit cellula filia in rei civibus laude clamaverunt donavit potest flens non solutionem innocentem si quod ait. Una Christi sanguine concomitatur quia quod non coepit, volvitur ingreditur est Apollonius eius non potentiae. Coepit cenam inhaeret Visceribusque esocem manibus modi regiam iriure dolore. Filiam in rei finibus veteres hoc ambulare manu in fuerat eum istam provoces.
</div>

<button name="toggleContentEditable">disable contenteditable</button>
```

CSS

```
/*======   DragonDrop Demo CSS
Basically, user-select, and user-drag (and all their prefixes) need to be set in a way that lets the browser know which parts of our draggable element are selectable and draggable and which aren't.
    So I guess this is that.
                   ======*/
@charset utf-8;

/* these rules only apply to fancy boxes when contenteditable is true: they are necessary for the drag-and-drop demo to work correctly */
[contenteditable="true"] .fancy {
    /**/-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none; /* without this line, element can be dragged within itself! No-no! */
    /**/-moz-user-drag:element;-webkit-user-drag:element;
    user-drag:element; /* makes the whole fancy box draggable */
    cursor:move !important; } /* switches to the move cursor */
    [contenteditable="true"] .fancy * {
        /**/-moz-user-drag:none;-webkit-user-drag:none;
        user-drag:none; } /* hopefully disables the internal default dragging of the img */



/*======     Everything below this area
               is STRICLY for STYLE
                 and VISUAL APPEAL.
              It shouldn't concern you.    ======*/

html,body{ height:100%; }
[contenteditable] {
    background:#f8f8f8; box-sizing:border-box; padding:2%; min-height:auto;
    font-size:10px; font-family:sans-serif; color:#444;
    border-bottom:2px dashed #888; }
    .fancy {
        display:inline-block; margin:10px;
        color:#444; text-align:center; font-style:italic;
        font-size:10px; font-family:sans-serif;
        background:#fff; border:8px solid white;
        box-shadow:1px 2px 8px #444;
        cursor:pointer; }
        .fancy img {
            display:block; margin-bottom:2px;
            border:1px solid white;
            box-shadow:0 1px 6px #888; }
        .fancy .caption { max-width:100px; }
    h1 { font-weight:bold; font-size:1.4em; }
    h2 { font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; text-indent:2px; }
    p { text-indent:8px; }
    strong { font-weight:bold; }
button { display:block; margin:6px auto; }
```

Javascript

```
/*

==== Dragon Drop: a demo of precise DnD
          in, around, and between 
         multiple contenteditable's.

=================================
== MIT Licensed for all to use ==
=================================
Copyright (C) 2013 Chase Moskal

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
============

*/

function DRAGON_DROP (o) {
    var DD=this;

    // "o" params:
    DD.$draggables=null;
    DD.$dropzones=null;
    DD.$noDrags=null; // optional

    DD.dropLoad=null;
    DD.engage=function(o){
        DD.$draggables = $(o.draggables);
        DD.$dropzones = $(o.dropzones);
        DD.$draggables.attr('draggable','true');
        DD.$noDrags = (o.noDrags) ? $(o.noDrags) : $();
        DD.$dropzones.attr('dropzone','copy');
        DD.bindDraggables();
        DD.bindDropzones();
    };
    DD.bindDraggables=function(){
        DD.$draggables = $(DD.$draggables.selector); // reselecting
        DD.$noDrags = $(DD.$noDrags.selector);
        DD.$noDrags.attr('draggable','false');
        DD.$draggables.off('dragstart').on('dragstart',function(event){
            var e=event.originalEvent;
            $(e.target).removeAttr('dragged');
            var dt=e.dataTransfer,
                content=e.target.outerHTML;
            var is_draggable = DD.$draggables.is(e.target);
            if (is_draggable) {
                dt.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                dt.setData('text/plain',' ');
                DD.dropLoad=content;
                $(e.target).attr('dragged','dragged');
            }
        });
    };
    DD.bindDropzones=function(){
        DD.$dropzones = $(DD.$dropzones.selector); // reselecting
        DD.$dropzones.off('dragleave').on('dragleave',function(event){
            var e=event.originalEvent;

            var dt=e.dataTransfer;
            var relatedTarget_is_dropzone = DD.$dropzones.is(e.relatedTarget);
            var relatedTarget_within_dropzone = DD.$dropzones.has(e.relatedTarget).length>0;
            var acceptable = relatedTarget_is_dropzone||relatedTarget_within_dropzone;
            if (!acceptable) {
                dt.dropEffect='none';
                dt.effectAllowed='null';
            }
        });
        DD.$dropzones.off('drop').on('drop',function(event){
            var e=event.originalEvent;

            if (!DD.dropLoad) return false;
            var range=null;
            if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) { // Chrome
                range=document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
            }
            else if (e.rangeParent) { // Firefox
                range=document.createRange(); range.setStart(e.rangeParent,e.rangeOffset);
            }
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);

            $(sel.anchorNode).closest(DD.$dropzones.selector).get(0).focus(); // essential
            document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'<param name="dragonDropMarker" />'+DD.dropLoad);
            sel.removeAllRanges();

            // verification with dragonDropMarker
            var $DDM=$('param[name="dragonDropMarker"]');
            var insertSuccess = $DDM.length>0;
            if (insertSuccess) {
                $(DD.$draggables.selector).filter('[dragged]').remove();
                $DDM.remove();
            }

            DD.dropLoad=null;
            DD.bindDraggables();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
    DD.disengage=function(){
        DD.$draggables=$( DD.$draggables.selector ); // reselections
        DD.$dropzones=$( DD.$dropzones.selector );
        DD.$noDrags=$( DD.$noDrags.selector );
        DD.$draggables.removeAttr('draggable').removeAttr('dragged').off('dragstart');
        DD.$noDrags.removeAttr('draggable');
        DD.$dropzones.removeAttr('droppable').off('dragenter');
        DD.$dropzones.off('drop');
    };
    if (o) DD.engage(o);
}



$(function(){

    window.DragonDrop = new DRAGON_DROP({
        draggables:$('.fancy'),
        dropzones:$('[contenteditable]'),
        noDrags:$('.fancy img')
    });

    // This is just the enable/disable contenteditable button at the bottom of the page.
    $('button[name="toggleContentEditable"]').click(function(){
        var button=this;
        $('[contenteditable]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('contenteditable')==='true') {
                $(this).attr('contenteditable','false');
                $(button).html('enable contenteditable');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
                $(button).html('disable contenteditable');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/T2zHQ/

Comment: Cool, I have just checked that out. I've only looked at it for a few mins, It's does seem a bit buggy on the drag-able after you drop it the first time, but that is to be expected as I'm not asking for code off anyone. I will take a good look at it in a minute and get back to you. This could probably be the best answer. Maybe.

Comment: I was working on your code when I stumbled upon this different approach by Chase. Seems like the way to go, as it also allows the user to place the image at specific points inside a text node. The result is much closer to what we have in word processing and desktop publishing WYSIWYG applications, comparing to what we had with the previous method.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a very effective solution and I'm going to re-write it from scratch but at least I have the idea. I was beginning to loose hope before your answer.

Comment: there is a small issue though, if you start dragging but drop in place the element simply disappear.

Comment: @TecHunter yes, I also noticed that... but i did say that i was going to re-write it from scratch anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I would consider using jQuery UI's **[Sortable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)**. The **[portlets example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets)** handles the `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` requirement. I've created a simple **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hqDJ/1/)** that builds upon the portlets example and also satisfies the `prepend` and `append` requirement.

This is just a start for you that I'm sure you can manipulate as you need. [`connectWith`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith) is important depending on where you want to allow things to be placed.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hqDJ/1/)**

***JS***

```
$(".column").sortable({
    items: ".portlet",
    connectWith: ".column"
});
$(".portlet").sortable({
    items: ".portlet-content",
    connectWith: ".portlet"
});
$(".column").disableSelection();
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <div class="portlet-content">One. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <div class="portlet-content">Two. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <div class="portlet-content">Three. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <div class="portlet-content">Four. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <div class="portlet-content">Five. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a possibility, but when I said in my comment that I don't mind jQuery answers because I can re-write it in vanilla, I didn't mean I was happy to re-write **`1278`** lines of jQuery

Comment: @Pinocchio Yeah, I can understand that. I was hesitant to provide this as an answer but after I saw how simple it was with jqUI I had to offer. I'm sure someone else can provide a better and more bug free plain JS solution than I have time for if the 500 bounty is tempting enough for them ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your understanding, I certainly do hope so. I don't honestly think that I will be getting any answers that solve the problem with JS, But we have 4 days left, we shall just have to wait and see. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Pincocchio - if this solves your problem just include jQuery in your Angular project.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet That's almost like saying just add **Twenty Five Thousand** Lines of code to your app, just for drag and drop.

Comment: Twenty Five Thousand Lines of code you didn't have to write and which come out at a pretty meagre 32kb when minified and zipped. Here's another idea, try the plugin with jQLite and make any changes necessary to get it working.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet We're not just talking about jQuery here, jQuery UI is a lot bigger than jQuery its self.

Comment: Why not use jQuery + UI? If you're making a big JS app, what's a few more lines of JS? I'd normally agree with you, but in this case jQuery + UI actually adds something. And it's unobtrusive. Something invention something wheel something.

Comment: @Rudie it's not just a few more lines, i just don't see how there is a lot of *professional* developers that would recommend me to link up jQuery & jQuery UI just to use the sortable widget.

Comment: @Pinocchio The alternative, as someone mentioned before, is writing your own, buggy, worse code that'll take you a long time. The # LOC don't matter. It's 50KB on a probably huge app, so take that man. I'm not a jQuery fan at all, but THIS is the case where it actually adds something. Doesn't matter. You like rolling your own =) I get that. What about Zepto? Even smaller.

Answer (score 3):

[interact.js](https://github.com/taye/interact.js) is a standalone, lightweight drag-and-drop and resize javascript module for mobile and desktop (including IE8+) with support for interacting with HTML and SVG elements. It only captures and calculates drag user input and it leaves all of the styling and visual feedback up to you.

I've updated the JS fiddle with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mLX5A/6/

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    container = document.getElementById('container');

// make an Interactable of the box
interact(box)
// make a draggable of the Interactable
.draggable(true)
    .on('dragmove', function (event) {
        event.target.x |= 0;
        event.target.y |= 0;

        event.target.x += event.dx,
        event.target.y += event.dy;

        // translate the element by the change in pointer position
        event.target.style[transformProp] =
            'translate(' + event.target.x + 'px, ' + event.target.y + 'px)';
    });

// Then to make #container a dropzone dropzone:
interact('#container')      // or interact(document.getElementById('container'))
    .dropzone(true)
    .on('drop', function (event) {
        // target is the dropzone, relatedTarget was dropped into target

        event.relatedTarget.x = 0;
        event.relatedTarget.y = 0;
        event.relatedTarget.style[transformProp] = '';

        var siblings = container.querySelectorAll('p'),
            len = siblings.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var rect = interact(siblings[i]).getRect();

            if (event.pageY < rect.top) {
                return siblings[i].parentNode
                    .insertBefore(event.relatedTarget, siblings[i]);
            }
        }

        return container.appendChild(event.relatedTarget);
    });

// CSS transform vendor prefixes
transformProp = 'transform' in document.body.style ?
    'transform' : 'webkitTransform' in document.body.style ?
    'webkitTransform' : 'mozTransform' in document.body.style ?
    'mozTransform' : 'oTransform' in document.body.style ?
    'oTransform' : 'msTransform';
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to do something what I know.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
     <div class="draggable"> alsdf dsalf asdfsadf
    dsaf sadfldsaf sadkf sadlfsadf
    asdf safdsafdksadf sadf lasldkfjsaldf safdsa
    dfsadflsadf asdlfsafdsafdsa
    fsafdsadf safdls
    </div>
    <div class="draggable"> alsdf dsalf asdfsadf
    dsaf sadfldsaf sadkf sadlfsadf
    asdf safdsafdksadf sadf lasldkfjsaldf safdsa
    dfsadflsadf asdlfsafdsafdsa
    fsafdsadf safdls
    </div>
    <div class="draggable"> alsdf dsalf asdfsadf
    dsaf sadfldsaf sadkf sadlfsadf
    asdf safdsafdksadf sadf lasldkfjsaldf safdsa
    dfsadflsadf asdlfsafdsafdsa
    fsafdsadf safdls
    </div>
    <div class="draggable"> alsdf dsalf asdfsadf
    dsaf sadfldsaf sadkf sadlfsadf
    asdf safdsafdksadf sadf lasldkfjsaldf safdsa
    dfsadflsadf asdlfsafdsafdsa
    fsafdsadf safdls
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var drag = new function(){
      this.box;
      this._cnt;
      this.hvEle;
      this.trgEle;
      this.initX;
      this.initY;
      this.dragging=false;
};
$(document).on('mousedown','#box',function(){
    drag.box = $(this);  
    initX = drag.box.offset().left;
    initY = drag.box.offset().top;

    drag._cnt = drag.box.closest('.container');
    drag.hvEle = drag._cnt.find('.draggable');
    drag.box.css({position:"absolute"});

    drag.hvEle.mousemove(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        drag.dragging=true;
        drag.box.css({cursor:"move"});
        drag.hvEle.removeClass('dragHv');
        drag.trgEle = $(this);
        drag.trgEle.addClass('dragHv');
        var x =  e.pageX ||e.clientX;
        var y =  e.pageY ||e.clientY;
        drag.box.css({left:x,top:y});

    });

    drag.box.mouseup(function(e){        
         drag.trgEle.append(drag.box);
        /***** You can write your required logic here to either append or
         insertBefore or insertAfter
        ****/
        drag.box.css({position:'static',cursor:"move"}); 
         drag.hvEle.unbind('mousemove');
         drag.box.unbind('mouseup');
         drag.dragging=false;
     });
});
$('.container').disableSelection();
```

**This is additional logic to make sure that element is not dropped out of the container element**

```
$(document).on('mousemove','html',function(){
    if(drag.dragging){
        drag.box.css({cursor:"no-drop"});
    }
});
$(document).on('mouseup','html',function(){
    if(drag.dragging){
        drag.box.css({left:drag.initX,top:drag.initY,position:"static"});
        drag.box.css({cursor:"move"});
        drag.hvEle.unbind('mousemove');
        drag.box.unbind('mouseup');
        dragging=false;
    }
});
**Styles****

    .container{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;    
      border:1px solid green;
    }
    .draggable{
     padding:10px 5px;
    }
    .draggable:nth-child(even){
      background:#efefef;
      border-bottom:1px solid black;
      border-top:1px solid black;
    }
    #box{
     height:50px;
     width:200px;
     background:red;
     cursor:move;   
    }
    .dragHv{
        background-color:yellow !important;
    }
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3rcj/1/).

I hope that It would help you at least by some way.

Answer (score -1):

Pinocchio, I would suggest you to create some sort of preview droppable design before you drop (a new onmouseover/mouseenter preview), I bielive that would help you in envolve your algoritmn.

I would also abandon using getFromPoint (for cross-browsing support), instead I would use JQuery mouseenter / mouseleave to assign the hovering element of the time for mouseup/dropping.

With the hovering element in hand and also its position (jQquery.position)  relative to the document you can somehow make your calculations based on the cursor position for appending or prepending an element.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'm not worried about browser support, but anyway `elementFromPoint` is supported in **IE5+ FF3+** and i don't really understand your point. :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised no-one mentioned the [jQuery UI "Draggable"](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) feature! It's pretty powerful and customize-able rather than trying to build your own.

Comment: As you can see in the demo I have provided I am quite capable of making something drag-able, that is not the issue here. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @Pinocchio I've checked that, seems like you spent alot making this thing (which you already mentioned in the question description). You "can" (but it's upto you) make use of jQuery UI "Draggable" and maybe "Sortable" to achieve what you are trying to do. I mean, "draggable" and "sortable" are well-developed and can save you hours/days/weeks of work